# Tagged articles not being shown in Smart Search results

Tags: articles, tags, smartsearch

I have an issue with tagged articles not being shown in smart search results.

I have a test article:

Title = "This is a test article"
Content = "descriptiontest"
Tag = "taggedtest"

I have then indexed new content.

If I search by "test", the article is shown in the Smart Search results.

If I search by "descriptiontest", the article is shown in the Smart Search 
results.

If I search by "taggedtest", the tag is shown in the Smart Search results, but I want the article to be shown in the Smart Search results.

How can I get an article to be shown in the Smart Search results when searching by tag?